# Strange network hops to Microsoft Office 365 server

Tags: networking, dns, traceroute

Let me start by saying, that I'm not a network pro and trying to learn.

We have some issues with Office 365 and when I try to ping their IP (132.245.228.194) I get this result. Notice that in hop 7 the IP is my own IP - is that normal?

Here's the trace result...

```
Tracing route to 132.245.228.194 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.0.1
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  x.x.x.x (ISP provider)
  3    14 ms    14 ms    14 ms  ams-ix.zensystems.net [80.249.209.220]
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5    16 ms    15 ms    15 ms  ae17-0.ams-96c-1a.ntwk.msn.net [191.234.84.54]
  6    16 ms    15 ms    15 ms  ae10-0.am3-96c-1a.ntwk.msn.net [191.234.81.135]
  7    15 ms    15 ms    17 ms  x.x.x.x (Our IP)
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9    15 ms    15 ms    15 ms  132.245.228.194
```

Is this normal?

Thanks

Comment: The name server on IP 132.245.228.194 is outlook.office365.com, http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/132.245.228.194 so it seems to be normal

Comment: Yeah, but I'm confused why trace hops out ouf my network and suddently in hop 7 is back in my network - is this normal?

Comment: Its a router or firewall changing the TTL value. Traceroute is a bit of a "hack" in how it functions. Google for an explanation(there are plenty)